# How can I listen when my view is scroll out of visible region

Tags: android

In my android application, I have a scroll view which has a lot of children view.
How can I listen for an event when a view is switching from visible to 'non visible to user' due to user's scroll action?

Comment: What type of event? touch? key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the default ScrollView does not provide any sort of scroll listener, but it does call `onScrollChanged()` when the user scrolls, so you can implement your own:

```
public class YourScrollView extends ScrollView {
  private ScrollListener scrollListener;

  ... // constructors etc

  public void setScrollListener(ScrollListener scrollViewListener) {
    this.scrollListener = scrollViewListener;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onScrollChanged(int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy) {
    super.onScrollChanged(x, y, oldx, oldy);

    if (scrollListener != null) {  //I don't care about the direction, you might.
      scrollListener.onScrollChanged(); 
    }
  }

  public static interface ScrollListener {
    public void onScrollChanged();
  }

}
```

Now in your `onScrollChanged` you can go through your Views and check if they are visible:

```
int[] location = {0,0};
view.getLocationOnScreen(location);

//container height is the height of the scrollview
if (location[1] + view.getBottom() < 0 || location[1]  > containerHeight) {
  //your view is not visible
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is it that you want to achieve? Perhaps there are other solutions that we could suggest.

You could add an `onVisibilityChanged` event handler to the child views. This is called when the visibility of the view changes. Android documentation on this can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onVisibilityChanged%28android.view.View,%20int%29).

Comment: `onVisibilityChanged` is not called when the view is scrolled out. It is called for example by `setVisibility`.